# try to combine all line of texts which have different format in one bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, paint, abstraction

what im doing now is render the text into the bitmap. its done. then, there had many line of texts. every line have different formats. how about if i want to try to combine all lines which have different format in one bitmap. Is that can? is it using abstraction?

Comment: It should be possible using the Canvas. "Is it using abstraction?" What do you mean by that? All computer programs use abstraction. Did you mean another word?

Comment: i trying to combile the whole line in one image. for example:


line 1 =  text: profile format:align center,size=20
line 2 = text: name: danial format: align left, size=10

want to combine line 1 and 2 become one image but have different format. is that can?